# Missing Utility Control on View menu

Tags: ssms, sql-server-2016

I am trying to open Utility Control from View Menu, but can't find it. I am using SQL Server 2016 (SP1), Developer Edition and SSMS version 17.1. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like its not added to SSMS 17. There is a connect report regarding this:

[Link to the Connect Report](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/3134389/sql-server-utility-explorer-missing-from-ssms-v17-0)